# Project Reactor test never completes

Tags: project-reactor

I have created a simple Kafka consumer that returns a `Flux` of objects (the received messages) and I'm trying to test  it using the `StepVerifier`.

In my test, I do something like that:

```
Flux<Pojo> flux = consumer.start();
StepVerifier.create(flux)
  .expectNextMatches(p -> p.getList().size() == 3)
  .verifyComplete();
```

The assertion works ok (if I change the value from `3` to something else, the test fails). But, if the assertion passes, than the test never exit.

I have also tried to use the `verify` method like so:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux)
  .expectNextMatches(f -> f.getEntitlements().size() == 3)
  .expectComplete()
  .verify(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
```

In this case, I get this error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: VerifySubscriber timed out on false
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Kafka `Flux` is probably infinite, so it never emits the `onComplete` signal, which the test waits for. You can call `.thenCancel().verify()` if you're only interested in testing that first value.

Comment: Yes, this! I got to the same conclusion. I missed the "thenCancel()" API. Thanks